# Navigation drawer / fragment update

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer setup. One of my fragments on the drawer allows the user to upload an image and the image is then displayed. The image uploads and displays fine but if the user leaves the fragment and returns the image view loads nothing and displays empty not even the placeholder image. The same image is also displayed in the navigation drawer but does not update until the user leaves the app and returns the place holder image will also not display here.

Profile fragment

```
        mUsersDB.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        String name = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_NAME);
                        mName.setText(name);

                        String status = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_STATUS);
                        mStatus.setText(status);

                        String image = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_IMAGE);

                        if (mDisplayImage.getDrawable() == null){

                            mDisplayImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_no_profile_picture);


                        } else {

                            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image).into(mDisplayImage);
                        }


                        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


                    } else {

                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

Navigation drawer:

```
        mUsersDB.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        String name = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_NAME);

                        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                        TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.menu_userName);
                        navUsername.setText(name);

                        String image = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_IMAGE);

                        ImageView navImage = headerView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(image)
                                .into(navImage);
```

I found online that they were talking about detaching and re attaching the listener but i dont have a listener setup so i dont understand how i would be able to implement that in also i found to use .setdrawerlistner but that has been deprecated. Lost at this point any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: "One of my fragments on the drawer..." Do you really have a fragment on the navigation drawer?

Comment: No I worded it poorly will update it the fragment is a tab on the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

I was going about it the wrong way i simply used a place holder with glide using request options

```
                            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.no_profile_picture)
                                .error(R.drawable.no_profile_picture)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .priority(Priority.HIGH);

                        ImageView navImage = headerView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(image)
                                .apply(options)
                                .into(navImage);
```